# Ввод данных в SQLite и их получение

Tags: java, android, sqlite

При старте Fragment в 16 его EditText должны загрузиться данные из БД. Далее после закрытия Fragment введенные данные должны быть внесены в БД. При последующих открытиях этого Fragment опять должны загружаться те же данные, но уже с внесенными до этого изменениями. Вопрос: как такое сделать? Ну хотя бы в 4 EditText для начала, а то много писать выйдет.

Вот класс DBHelper:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "FirstDatabase";
public static final String TABLE_RINGS = "rings";

public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_START = "start";
public static final String KEY_END = "end";

public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_RINGS + "(" + KEY_ID
            + " integer primary key," + KEY_START + " text," + KEY_END + " text" + ")");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + TABLE_RINGS);

    onCreate(db);

    }
}
```

Вот фрагмент (выдает ошибку):

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class FragmentRings extends Fragment {
    DBHelper dbHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase database;
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(getActivity());
        EditText one = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.oneurok);
        EditText oneee = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        EditText two = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.twourok);
        EditText twooo = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.editText3);

        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor userCursor = database.query(DBHelper.TABLE_RINGS, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (userCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        while (!userCursor.isAfterLast()) {
            String data = userCursor.getString(userCursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_START));
            String data1 = userCursor.getString(userCursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_END));
            one.setText(data);
            oneee.setText(data1);
            userCursor.moveToNext();
            String data2 = userCursor.getString(userCursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_START));
            String data3 = userCursor.getString(userCursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_END));
            two.setText(data);
            twooo.setText(data1);
        }
    }
    userCursor.close();


}

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        EditText one = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.oneurok);
        EditText oneee = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        EditText two = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.twourok);
        EditText twooo = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.editText3);

        contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_START, one.getText().toString());
        contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_END, oneee.getText().toString());
        contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_START, two.getText().toString());
        contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_END, twooo.getText().toString());
        database.insert(DBHelper.TABLE_RINGS, null, contentValues);
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View RingsView =
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rings, container, false);
        return RingsView;
    }
}
```

Лог ошибки при открытии фрагмента на эмуляторе:

```
08-01 16:49:24.686 3339-3339/com.churkin.myproject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL 
EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.churkin.myproject, PID: 3339

android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 7 requested, with a 
size of 7
at 
android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:426)
at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
at 
com.churkin.myproject.FragmentRings.onStart(FragmentRings.java:70)
at 
android.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:2077)
at 
android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:922)
at 
android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
at 
android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:834)
at 

android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1452)
at 
android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:447)
at 
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Так а в чем именно проблема?

Comment: @АндроидАндроид не знаю как сделать правильную реализацию в фрагменте. Код, который я привел в фрагменте, выдает ошибку

Comment: @АндроидАндроид сейчас прикреплю log

Comment: У вас цикл чтения курсора неверный. Пытаетесь прочесть по две записи за итерацию. Вот и падает, потому что записей семь, нечет, по две не прочесть :) Перепишите цикл.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja да я так и понял, только не знаю как его переписать то ) Первый раз дело имею с SQLite

Comment: Незачем каждый раз искать в `onStart` и `onStop` view для работы с ними. Сделайте это один раз в `onCreateView` и сохраните найденные view в поля класса.

Comment: @temq сначала оценил ваш ответ кнопкой вверх, потом понял что получил NullPointerException благодаря вам :D Нельзя в onCreateView использовать метод getView(). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495898/findviewbyid-in-fragment

Comment: Ну конечно нельзя, надо использовать view которую заинфлатили.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так правильно работать с курсором в вашем случае

```
Cursor userCursor = database.query(DBHelper.TABLE_RINGS, null, null, null, null, null, null);
if (userCursor != null ) {
  if  (userCursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        // читаем только одну запись, никаких переходов дальше
        String data = userCursor.getString(userCursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_START));
        String data1 = userCursor.getString(userCursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_END));
        // заносим данные в UI
        // ...
    } while (userCursor.moveToNext());
  }
  userCursor.close();
}
```

Если у вас только две пары контролов, читайте только первые две записи и `break` из цикла.

Comment: Достаточно лишь обычного цикла `while (userCursor.moveToNext()) {}` без дополнительных проверок. Так будет короче и красивее.

Comment: Это стандартный code snippet, автор разберется как это работает, пусть укорачивает.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja ну в два то EditView я считаю и занесу, а в другие как занести? У меня же их много, нужно чтобы во все 16 заносилось... А ключа то всего 2... Может проверку какую-нибудь сделать дополнительную, если дальше курсора еще строк нету, то ничего не делать, а если есть, то дальше заносить... И к тому же, корректно занести данные в базу более чем с двух EditView не выходит

Comment: @АлександрЧуркин, а в чем проблема? При каждой итерации цикла, у вас будет пара значений из строки БД, сколько строк в таблице, столько пар данных. Как вы их по UI растолкаете, решайте сами.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja ааа, понял, спасибо) Вы мне так сказать открыли глаза) Во многих моментах казалось бы не самых простых получается интуитивно иногда, потом разбираю... А с SQLite видимо мне конкретно было нужно, чтобы кто-то объяснил "на пальцах"))