# Ошибка при выводе значения из SQLite в TextView

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
public class ViewNote extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView viewTheme;
TextView viewText;
ImageButton lightRed, lightYellow, lightGreen, addPhoto;
ImageView addedPhoto;

DBHelper dbHelper;
SQLiteDatabase db;
Cursor cursor;

int num;
long noteId;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_note);

    viewTheme = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edNewThemeNotes);
    viewText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edNewTextNotes);

    lightRed = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.edLightRed);
    lightYellow = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.edLightYellow);
    lightGreen = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.edLightGreen);
    addPhoto = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.edAddPhoto);

    addedPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.edAddedPhoto);

    dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        noteId = extras.getLong("id");
    }

    if (noteId > 0) {
        String[] notesStr = new String[]{DBHelper.KEY_THEME, DBHelper.KEY_TEXT};
        cursor = db.query("notes", notesStr, "_id = ?", new String[]{Long.toString(noteId)}, null, null, null);

        if(cursor!= null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {

                    String themeColumnIndex = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_THEME));
                    String textColumnIndex = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_TEXT));

                    viewTheme.append(themeColumnIndex);
                    viewText.append(textColumnIndex);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_view_note, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.edDeleteNote:
            db.delete(DBHelper.TABLE_NOTES, "_id = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(noteId)});
            goHome();
            break;

        case R.id.edSaveNote:
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

            contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_THEME, viewTheme.getText().toString());
            contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_TEXT, viewText.getText().toString());
            contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_PRIORITY, viewText.getText().toString());

            if (noteId > 0) {
                db.update(DBHelper.TABLE_NOTES, contentValues, DBHelper.KEY_ID + "=" + String.valueOf(noteId), null);
            }


            break;
    }
    return false;
}

public void onClick(View view) {

    int id = view.getId();

    if (id == R.id.edLightRed) {
        num = 1;
    }

    else if (id == R.id.edLightYellow){
        num = 2;
    }

    else if (id == R.id.edLightGreen){
        num = 3;
    }

    else {
        num = 0;
    }
}

private void goHome(){
    // закрываем подключение
    db.close();
    // переход к главной activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

```
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.readyfo.smartnotes.ViewNote.onCreate(ViewNote.java:67)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Какой-то параметер == null. Как видно ошибка вылезает сразу при запуске Activity.

Comment: @Eugen Осталось понять какой) "noteId " точно не зануленный, ибо он обрабатывается в удалении.  Остаётся "cursor", но вот вопрос: "Почему?"

Comment: но курсор ты тоже проверяешь `if(cursor!= null) {` дальше по коду, так что не может быть нулевым.

Comment: хотя `cursor.close();` находится вне `if`! попробуй поместить внутрь.

Comment: Что у Вас на 67-ой строке?

Comment: @woesss Вывожу в TextView значение из БД.

Comment: Конкретно какой код в этой строке? У Вас ошибка указывает на строку 67.

Comment: @woesss viewTheme.append(themeColumnIndex);

Comment: Скорее всего значение в колонке равно `null` - попробуйте обернуть так: `viewTheme.append(String.valueOf(themeColumnIndex));` и вторую, соответственно.